# What is the difference between $E[\varepsilon\mid X]=0$ and $E[\varepsilon X]=0$ in OLS regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, expected-value, assumptions

Why is the assumption  $E[\varepsilon X]=0$ weaker than  $E[\varepsilon\mid X]=0$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm just looking from a probabilistic perspective, and looking forward to hear other ideas. Using law of iterated expectations, we have
$$E[\epsilon X]=E[E[\epsilon X\mid X]]=E[X E[\epsilon\mid X]]$$
If $E[\epsilon\mid X]$ is $0,$ then automatically, $E[\epsilon X]$ is $0.$ But, the other way around is not true, which means $E[\epsilon X]$ is a weaker condition.

Comment: Indeed (+1). In fact $E(u\mid X) = 0 \implies E[f(X)u] = 0$ for any function $f$.